# How do I connect to the Database on a different server?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames

I have a machine A which has DB server on it.
I have a machine B which has Oracle Client installed on it.

I modified the tnsnames.ora file in machine B by adding the following:

```
  TRIAL1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = machineName.example.com)(PORT = 1521)(QUEUESIZE=100))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Trial1.world)
    )
  )
```

Yet, I cannot run the command `sqlplus name/pwd@trial as sysdba` on machine B successfully. It throws an error stating "insufficient privileges". Are there any modifications needed on the sqlnet.ora or tnsnames.ora file on machine A?

Comment: Do you need to be connecting `as sysdba` - are you connecting to an administrator account? It's that which is causing the error. If you connect as a normal user without that clause it should work as it is. If you do need to connect remotely as an administrator then there are additional things you need to do, but not sure if that's necessary?

Comment: Yes, Alex, I'm trying to connect to the administrator account. What additional things do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to connect remotely as sysdba you need to grant that system privilege to user that needs to do that.

```
grant sysdba to name;
```

From now on you can connect from any machine using `sqlplus name/pwd@trial1 as sysdba`. The name is the username defined in the database that you connect to, no matter from which OS account you connect or from which machine you connect, as long as the connection can be made.

Question that remains is: do you need to work as sysdba in that database. Don't do that unless you know what you are doing. Effectively you work as SYS, the owner of the catalog. The slightest typo can make your database dead as a dodo.

For most, even a regular dba account is already too much. Create a regular account ASAP give it the needed privileges and use that one to do your work. The needed privileges are the minimal privs needed to do the job (create session, create table, create procedure etc. (almost certainly not dba))

Comment: @Zelf, so assuming I need to grant the privileges to the user "User" on machineB.example.com, the following would be the command?
--> grant sysdba to User@machineB.example.com

Comment: No, in you database you connect locally as sysdba and grant sysdba to the username that is already defined inside that database. This is not using host authentication.

Comment: My question is how to grant privileges to a "User" of machine-B to be able to access the DB on machine-A.

Comment: Your question is about connect to name@trial1, that question I answered. Remote OS authentication is an other question.